# Closed forms and left invariance

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Im trying to prove that, for an Abelian Lie group $G$ every left invariant  $m$-form is closed.

I am aware of the structure theorem of commutative Lie groups, but I tried something else:

For $\omega \in \bigwedge^m \mathbb{R}^n$ I apply the exterior derivative:

$$ d \omega (V_0,...,V_m) =\sum_{0 \leq i<j \leq m} (-1)^{i+j} \omega([V_i,V_j], V_0,...,\hat{V_i},...,\hat{V_j},...,V_m) $$

$$ \space\space\space\space\space+ \sum_{i=0}^m (-1)^i V_i \cdot \omega(V_0,...,\hat{V_i},...,V_m)$$

the first term vanishes because, for an Abelian group, every element commutes but I dont know what to do with the second term for it to be zero. How do I do this?

I should add that the hat notation tells us that the respective term is absent.

Comment: Where are you using left-invariance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost done. The first term vanishes because $G$ (hence $\mathfrak{g}$) is Abelian. Now you just have to note that since $\omega,V_0,\ldots, V_m$ are all left-invariant, then $\omega(V_0,\ldots, \hat{V_i},\ldots, V_m)$ is a constant (why?). And what is the derivative of a constant?

Comment: I dont understand why $\omega(V_0,...,\hat{V_i},...,V_m)$ becomes a constant with left invariance

Comment: Is it because its evaluated at the identity, then when we plug in the identity there it becomes a constant and then the derivitive of a constant is zero?

Comment: Yes, the constant value equals the value at the identity. Think of it like this: if $\omega, V_0,\ldots, V_m$ are left-invariant, so is the *function* $\omega(V_0,\ldots, \hat{V_i},\ldots, V_m)$. A left-invariant *function* is constant.

Comment: I was thinking about this and how do we deal with it if $\omega$ is a periodic function? This matter of left invariance applies to all elements of the group so any shift or translation (by any element) must leave $\omega$ invariant and thats why we can safely say that $\omega$ is a constant function, right?

Comment: I thought about $\sin(x) = \sin(x + 2\pi k)$ for example but it takes values of $\mathbb{R}$ while $\omega$ only takes the elements of the group as arguments so, if they are all left invariant then $\omega$ is a constant function, correct?

Comment: You seem to be extremely confused, $\omega$ is not a function! It's a differential form. I cannot imagine how did you get to periodicity from here. Use the *definition* of left-invariance to show that $\omega(V_0,\ldots,\hat{V_i},\ldots,V_m)$ is constant and equal to it's value at $e$.

Comment: Now I understand, sorry about that I was starting to confuse things